# How to make API post request with image to Rails API with paperclip from React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, paperclip

I am working on an app that has client side React and server side Ruby on Rails separately (meaning I am not using "react_on_rails" or "react-rails" gem). I am using `paperclip` gem to handle image in Rails.

I have model Post which has one image and attributes like following

```
# schema.rb
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "image"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "image_file_name"
    t.string "image_content_type"
    t.bigint "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.boolean "published", default: false
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end
```

Here is `post.rb`

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :image

    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

    belongs_to :user
    validates :title, :image, :content, presence: true

    has_many :users_posts, through: :bookmarks
    has_many :users_posts, through: :user_like_posts
    has_many :users_posts, through: :try_and_likes

    has_many :comments

    default_scope {order(published_at: :desc)}
end
```

And following is the new post form in React component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import CKEditor from "react-ckeditor-component";
import axios from 'axios';
import history from '../../history';
import { AuthWrapper } from '../../utils/auth_helpers';
import { getErrorMessages } from '../../utils/error_message_helpers';
import ErrorMessages from '../shared/ErrorMessages';

class NewPostForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: "", image: "", content: "", error_messages: [], client_image_url: ""
        }
        this.updateContent = this.updateContent.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleImageChange = this.handleImageChange.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }

    handleImageChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let image_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        this.setState({image: image_url});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const user = this.props.user;
        if (event.target.name === "save") {
            axios.post("/api/v1/users/" + user.id + "/posts?published=false",
                {
                    post: {
                        title: this.state.title, image: this.state.image, content: this.state.content,
                        user_id: user.id
                    }
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    history.replace("/community");
                }).catch((err) => {
                    let errors = getErrorMessages(err);
                    this.setState({error_messages: errors});
                });
        } else if (event.target.name === "post") {
            axios.post("/api/v1/users/" + user.id + "/posts?published=true",
                {
                    post: {
                        title: this.state.title, image: this.state.image, content: this.state.content,
                        user_id: user.id
                    }
                })
                .then(() => {
                    history.replace("/community");
                }).catch((err) => {
                    let errors = getErrorMessages(err);
                    this.setState({error_messages: errors});
                });
        }
    }

    updateContent(newContent) {
        this.setState({
            content: newContent
        })
    }

    onChange(evt) {
        var newContent = evt.editor.getData();
        this.setState({
            content: newContent
        })
    }

    onBlur(evt) {}

    afterPaste(evt) {}

    render() {
        let image_field = null;
        if (this.state.image === "") {
            image_field = <div className="customized-file-input-container"><input id="image-file" type="file" name="image" onChange={this.handleImageChange} className="customized-file-input" accept="image/*" required></input><label for="image-file"><i className="fa fa-upload"></i> Choose a file</label></div>
        } else {
            image_field = <img className="uploaded-post-image" src={this.state.image} alt=""></img>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Form id="new-post-container">
                    <h1>New Post</h1>
                    <ErrorMessages error_messages={this.state.error_messages} />
                    <p>Title</p>
                    <input className="form-control" type="text" name="title" onChange={this.handleChange} required></input>
                    <CKEditor
                        activeClass="p10"
                        content={this.state.content}
                        events={{
                            "blur": this.onBlur,
                            "afterPaste": this.afterPaste,
                            "change": this.onChange
                        }}
                    />
                    <div className="new-post-bottom-container">
                        {image_field}
                        <div>
                            <input className="btn color-reverse-button contact-submit-button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onClick={this.handleSubmit}></input>
                            <input className="btn color-reverse-button contact-submit-button" type="submit" name="post" value="Post" onClick={this.handleSubmit}></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const WrappedNewPostForm = AuthWrapper(NewPostForm);

export default WrappedNewPostForm;
```

I am using `createObjectURL()` to display the uploaded image in client side. I tried to use the "blob:...." URL that is generated for the image, but this one gave the following error.

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "blob:http://localhost:3000/4c001255-53ad-45c0-8261-d706c5132383"):
```

The problem with this is because the URL needs to start with "http", but this starts with "blob" as if I remove the "blob" part, it will not show this error, but another error saying it cannot find an image.
Does anyone know how to properly make post request to Rails API with image using `paperclip`?

Let me know if some important information is missing.

Answer (score -1):

**Deprecation Notice**

It is now highly recommended to use [ActiveStorage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html) for handling files on the server side in Rails due to reasons such as security and support. Paperclip is now deprecated for the purpose of encouraging developers to pursue ActiveStorage. Read more over why [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/closing-the-trombone).

Thanks to Thoughtbot and Rails.